# Bash script not work as expected

Tags: bash, bashrc

#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -- ssh -i "my.pem" ubuntu@''''''''''''''''.amazonaws.com && ./remote.sh

I want to connect the server to a new terminal and run the remote.sh command at the server

I am using the above script it opens the terminal and connects to the server but not executing the remote command

how can I execute it?

Comment: What is the contents of remote.sh? What version of Ubuntu? Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: something like $ tail -f  folder-one/folder-two/error.log

Comment: Something like? You do not know what is in your own script?

Comment: tail -f /home/ubuntu/project_lp/logs/error.log    , this is my script.

Comment: I‘m not familiar with the `gnome-terminal`, but the syntax for executing a script on the ssh target server is `ssh <user@server> <scriptname>`. The script must be stored on the target server. 
The use of `&&` results in a sequential execution, `remote.sh` will be executed as soon as the ssh command is finished. Guess it is the same inside the gnome-terminal.

Comment: @dummyuser when try  this way `ssh -i "my.pem" ubuntu@''''''''''''''''.amazonaws.com remote.sh` , it show the error  `bash: remote.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: remote.sh must exist on the server and be in the current directory where the user logs in.

Comment: @MubarisKunnath You may use the full path instead of a relative path. e.g. instead of `./remote.sh` `/home/ubuntu/bin/remote.sh`

Comment: its worked Thankyou guys